# Too many while loops inside one stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have one stored procedure in which I am getting comma separated values in parameters. I have three parameters which has comma separated values. And I need to put them in table's columns so I am using while loop. But I am scared when too many (say hundreds of thousands of users) users will connect to my website then my procedure will have performance issues.

Does anyone have better solution on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is interpreted, even though it is said to be 'compiled'. This means that your code might run faster if you simply break  up the strings outside the DB and execute multiple inserts instead of 1 call to a SQL proc which using interpreted SQL loops through the input.

Comment: Hi Frans! Thanks for your response. But can you elaborate what do you mean by break up strings outside DB?

Comment: I meant that instead of doing the string processing inside the DB, you might want to rewrite outside code + sql so that you can do string processing outside the SQL and use SQL only for operations directly on the data.